# ReactJs re-render on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I am trying to do a sequence of fetching some API data and manipulating it as follows:

1. Fetch list of string addresses via API
2. Convert each of this string addresses to a geocoded location via API
3. Displaying these geocoded addresses as markers on a map

I am having some trouble with getting the timing with all these asynchronous activities right (I am pretty new to Javascript).

Here's what I have so far:

```
class Map extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            addresses = [],
            geocodedAddresses = []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const geocodedAddresses = []
        fetch('.....')
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(addresses => this.setState({ addresses }, function() {
                this.state.addresses.forEach(address => {
                    Geocode.fromAddress(address).then(geocodedAddress => {
                        geocodedAddresses.push(geocodedAddress['results'][0]['geometry']['location'])
                    })
                })
            }))
            console.log(geocodedAddresses) //Correctly contains the geocoded addresses
            this.setState({ geocodedAddresses })
        }
    }

    render() {
        this.state.addresses.map(a => console.log(a)) //Evaluates correctly
        this.state.geocodedAddresses.map(ga => console.log(ga)) //Yields nothing....
    .....
    }
}
```

So I don't quite understand why React does not re render when I do `this.setState({ geocodedAddresses })` - Shouldn't react re render when I do setState?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple errors with your code. In the first place, the state object is being created with equals instead of colons:

```
this.state = {
    addresses: [],
    geocodedAddresses: []
}
```

In the second place, you should take into account that your code is asynchronous. Only when the promises generated by the call to `Geocode.fromAddress` resolve you have the data for your `geocodedAddresses`.

In the `componentDidMount`, you are console logging the `geocodedAdresses` and you report that you are seeing the right values. This is only because the log is update after the promises resolve. But when you do the `console.log` the value at that moment for `geocodedAdresses` is an empty array. And that is the value that is being inserted in the component `state`.

In order to set the correct value for the state, you should call `setState` when all your `Geocode.fromAddress` promises have resolved. In order to do that you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method.

So, your code would look like:

```
class Map extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            addresses: [],
            geocodedAddresses: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('.....')
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(addresses => {
                Promise.all(addresses.map(address => Geocode.fromAddress(address)))
                    .then(geocodedAddresses => {
                        this.setState({
                            addresses,
                            geocodedAddresses
                        })
                    });
            }))
        }
    }

    render() {
        this.state.addresses.map(a => console.log(a)) //Evaluates correctly
        this.state.geocodedAddresses.map(ga => console.log(ga)) //Yields nothing....
    .....
    }
}
```

Note that with this solution `setState` is only being called once.

Since all your `state` refers to addresses information, it could make sense to merge that information into a single key in the `state`. You could initialize your `state` in the constructor as:

```
this.state = {
    addresses: []
};
```

And then, you could populate the `state` once all the promises resolve:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('.....')
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(addresses => {
            Promise.all(addresses.map(address => Geocode.fromAddress(address)))
                .then(geocodedAddresses => {
                    const addressesState = addresses.map((address, i) => {
                        return {
                            address,
                            geocodedAddress: geocodedAddresses[i]
                        };
                    });
                    this.setState({ addresses: addressesState })
                });
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm - Without the brackets "[" in the Promise.all though (I guess since Array.map itself returns a list?

Comment: Could you comment on one thing: How could I modify your code if I wanted the addresses and geocodedAddresses in the same state (i.e this.state = { addresses: [{address: "someStringAddress", geocodedAddress: {lat, lng}}....]}

Comment: @Alex5207, I updated the code to correct the typo you detected and to expand the answer to take into account your last comment. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're right it's the async is slightly off. The `console.log` will populate *after* it "appears" in the console, but when `setState` has been called (and also when `console.log` has been called) its value is still `[]`.

if you're using `async/await` you can wait for the `fetch` chain to completely finish, or put the `setState` within the `then`. With the `setState` callback, it's probably better to do the latter.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const geocodedAddresses = []
  fetch('.....')
  .then(result => result.json())
    .then(addresses => this.setState({ addresses }, function() {
      this.state.addresses.forEach(address => {
        Geocode.fromAddress(address).then(geocodedAddress => {
          geocodedAddresses.push(geocodedAddress['results'][0]['geometry']['location'])
        })
      })
   console.log(geocodedAddresses) //Correctly contains the geocoded addresses
   this.setState({ geocodedAddresses })
}))

}}
```

or

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
      const geocodedAddresses = []
      let addresses = await fetch('.....').then(result => result.json())
      addresses.forEach(address => { // assuming this is sync
            Geocode.fromAddress(address).then(geocodedAddress => {
              geocodedAddresses.push(geocodedAddress['results'][0]['geometry']['location'])
            })
          })
       this.setState({ geocodedAddresses,addresses })

    }}
```